# .ParentTaskIdMapping properties in gantt of syncfusion does not work?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, syncfusion

I am using Syncfusion Essential Studio Edition Version 14.2.0.28 . When i am working with gantt chart and want to indent subtask/subsession inside of parent task/session then it does not work.I followed bellow link
https:
//help.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/gantt/data-binding?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp

Self-Referential Data Binding (Flat Data)

but till now does not work any one can suggest me? I shared 2 screen shot please follow

[Real Data where data displayed without parent child indentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZVHL.png)

[Gantt Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZOYe.png)

Answer (score 2):

To render the Gantt using Self Reference data source we need to consider the following things.

1. TaskId should be unique.
2. ParentId should be null for the parent Item.
3. For child items its parentId should be similar to its
   relevant parent item’s task id.

We need to map the taskId field in “taskIdMapping” and parentId using “parentTaskIdMapping”.

Please find our online demo sample for your reference

Sample: http://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/web/gantt/ganttselfreference

Regards,

Syncfusion Team

Answer (score -1):

Syncfusion Team, Finally I solved the problem that i faced.When i am using your sample Code from gantt-> Data Binding -> Self Referencial Data Binding(Flat Data) Sample Code.

It seems to me where you need to do this correction.According to your example.

Syncfusion Sample Code Snippet:

```
    public class Data

    {

        public string StartDate { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int ParentId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Duration { get; set; }

        public int PercentDone { get; set; }

        public List<Data> Children { get; set; }

        public string Predescessor { get; set; }



    }
```

The Change I made to make workable this sample is

```
    public class Data

    {

        public string StartDate { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        ***public int? ParentId { get; set; }***

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Duration { get; set; }

        public int PercentDone { get; set; }

        public List<Data> Children { get; set; }

        public string Predescessor { get; set; }



    }
```